# Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a small confusion in the dynamic memory allocation concept.
If we declare a pointer say a char pointer, we need to allocate adequate memory space.

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
str = "This is a string";
```

But this will also work.

```
char* str = "This is a string";
```

So in which case we have to allocate memory space?

Comment: Your confusion is about pointers, not dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve: There is one more alternative: `char str[] = "This is a string";`

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: I know I can use string. This is not part of any implementation. I just put these statements to remove my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are a special case in the language. Let's look closer at your code to understand this better:

First, you allocate a buffer in memory, and assign the address of that memory to `str`:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Then, you assign a string literal to `str`. This will overwrite what `str` held previously, so you will lose your dynamically allocated buffer, incidentally causing a memory leak. If you wanted to modify the allocated buffer, you would need at some point to dereference `str`, as in `str[0] = 'A'; str[1] = '\0';`.

```
str = "This is a string";
```

So, what is the value of `str` now? The compiler puts all string literals in static memory, so the lifetime of every string literal in the program equals the lifetime of the entire program. This statement is compiled to a simple assignment similar to `str = (char*)0x1234`, where `0x1234` is supposed to be the address at which the compiler has put the string literal.

That explains why this works well:

```
char* str = "This is a string";
```

Please also note that the static memory is not to be changed at runtime, so you should use `const char*` for this assignment.

> So in which case we have to allocate memory space?

In many cases, for example when you need to modify the buffer. In other words; when you need to point to something that could not be a static string constant.

Comment: `char* str = "This is a string";` does not "work well"; it is, in fact, both dangerous and deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

In first sample you have memory leak

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char)); 
str = "This is a string"; // memory leak
```

Allocated address will be replaced with new.
New address is an address for "This is a string".

And you should change second sample.

```
const char* str = "This is a string";
```

Because of "This is a string" is write protected area.

Comment: In which case I need a malloc, when I can do simply 
      char * str = "this is a string";

Comment: This is another question. If you write `char * str = "this is a string";` you are not allowed change any chars in your string. If you write `char * str = new char[20]` you can replace any char: `str[13]='a';`.

Comment: Now I got why my program used to crash when I was trying to modify a `char*`. So in fact it should be always `const char*`. Then why do `char*` exists?

Comment: `char*` exists in `C++` bacause it is allowed in `C`. But you're right. It should be always `const char *`.

Comment: @cppcoder: Backward-compatibility with C, which didn't have `const` when C++ was "forked" (or whatever you want to call the beginnings of C++'s development). It "works" but is deprecated, and if you use proper warning levels on your compiler, you'll be told off for it. It's properly invalid as of C++0x.

Answer (score 3):

The presumably C++98 code snippet

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
str = "This is a string";
```

does the following: (1) allocates 20 bytes, storing the pointer to that memory block in `str`, and (2) stores a pointer to a literal string, in `str`. You now have no way to refer to the earlier allocated block, and so cannot deallocate it. You have leaked memory.

Note that since `str` has been declared as `char*`, the compiler cannot practically detect if you try to use to modify the literal. Happily, in C++0x this will *not compile*. I really like that rule change!

The code snippet

```
char* str = "This is a string";
```

stores a pointer to a string literal in a `char*` variable named `str`, just as in the first example, and just as that example it won't compile with a C++0x compiler.

Instead of this sillyness, use for example `std::string` from the standard library, and sprinkle `const` liberally throughout your code.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you *dynamically* allocated memory off the heap. It can be modified, and it must be freed. In the second example, the compiler statically allocated memory, and it cannot be modified, and must not be freed. You must use a `const char*`, not a `char*`, for string literals to reflect this and ensure safe usage.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to a `char*` variable makes it point to something else, so why did you allocate the memory in the first place if you immediately forget about it? That's a memory leak. You probably meant this:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
strcpy(str, "This is a string");
// ...
free(str);
```

This will copy the second string to the first.
Since this is tagged C++, you should use a `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::string str = "This is a string";
```

No manual memory allocation and release needed, and assignment does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're just doing things wrong. You allocate dynamic memory on the heap and let `str` point to it. Then you just let `str` point to a string literal and the allocated memory is leaked (you don't copy the string into the allocated memory, you just change the address `str` is pointing at, you would have to use `strcpy` in the first example).

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to [Alexey Malistov's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408701/dynamic-memory-allocation/6408761#6408761) by adding that you can avoid memory leak in your first example by copying "This is a string" to `str` as in the following code:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
strcpy(str, "This is a string");
```

Please, note that by *can* I don't mean you *have* to. Its just adding to an answer to add value to this thread.

Comment: How do you guys keep up with the inflow of answers? There was like 1 answer when I started typing my answer, and after posting there's like 6 answers.